# EntityManager with aspectj is not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa, aspectj

I am trying aspectj with EntityManager, its giving error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
  Error creating bean with name
  'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration',
  Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
```

**POM:**

```xml
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.12</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <!-- <version>1.8.0</version> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>1.8.0</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcabi-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>0.22.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcabi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>ajc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

**Driver application:**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "aspect.*")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackages ="aspect.*")
public class Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        try {
            Service service=context.getBean(Service.class);
            service.save();

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught runtime exception");
        }
    }
}
```

**Service class:**

```java
@Component
public class Service{

    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void save() {
        System.out.println("Before Invocation");
        entityManager.persist(new Employee("009", "sunitha", "Lead"));
        System.out.println("after persist call");
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
   @Aspect
   @Component
   public class AuditAspect {

       @Around("execution(* javax.persistence.EntityManager.persist(..)) &&  @annotation(loggable)")
    public Object aroundServce(ProceedingJoinPoint  joinPoint, Loggable loggable) throws Throwable{
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      //  System.out.println("start--> "+start);
        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
        Logger.info(this, "info %s just called", MethodSignature.class.cast(joinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod().getName());
        return result;
    }

    }
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Need to know where am doing wrong??

Comment: As the message says ... it needs a Bean Validation API provider (Hibernate Validator, or Apache BVAL) in the CLASSPATH, so do what it says ?

Comment: Thanks dear. Its working After adding..
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: @NeilStockton Feel free to turn that comment into an answer, and get yourself some rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message says ... it needs a Bean Validation API (JSR 303) provider. If you put a provider like Hibernate-Validator or Apache BVAL in your CLASSPATH I'd expect the message to go away.